# regex pattern selects alternates matches

Tags: regex

Regex pattern

```
/("[^:=,]+":")(.*?)("}*\]*}*,")/
```

String :

```
"foo":""fooooooooooooooooooo"foooo","bar":"barrrrrrrrr""barrrrrr","fooo":"foooooo","bar":"barrrrrr","
```

Matches the first and the third pattern

http://rubular.com/r/S5fbsSfCjy

String:

```
"bar":"barrrrrrrrr""barrrrrr","fooo":"foooooo","bar":"barrrrrr","foo":""fooooooooooooooooooo"foooo","
```

Matches the first and the third pattern

http://rubular.com/r/hDfcBCkB2o

How do make it match all 4 patterns match any of the string above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the `,"` at the end of your regex pattern consumes the quotes from the following string. So, it is not matched. In fact, the regex will match only every alternate matching string.

You need to use look-ahead:

```
/("[^:=,]+":")(.*?)("}*\]*}*(?=,"))/
```

http://rubular.com/r/6v2OjPtmVM